# Why is a certified delivery person still prompte

Tags: docusignapi

I ran a quick test using a certified delivery recipient, one document, one signing point. Here is part of that request:

```
"compositeTemplates": [
{
  "serverTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "1",
      "templateId": "15a22617-4525-438c-aaf1-45f8632ba2d1"
    }
  ],
  "inlineTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "1",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [],
        "certifiedDeliveries": [
          {
            "name": "Kathy xxx",
            "email": "kathyxxx@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "accessCode": "12345",
            "customFields": [],
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "##Buyer1"
          }
        ]
```

I noticed if I used a document and template where the roleName matched and there were signing tabs, that the receiver would still be prompted for a signature, even though I put them as a certified delivery. I thought that certified delivery would mean just viewing the document, not ever having to sign it. I guess that's not the case. Is there any way to make sure that the certified delivery person only ever has to view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a RecipientType on a Server Template just does not feel like a good use of Server Templates. It means you have not defined your server template correctly. You should create another ServerTemplate with the appropriate recipient types and use that instead.

CompositeTemplates  allows you to extend your serverTemplates and enables you to overlay document, recipient, and tab definitions from multiple sources.

Sometimes it is better to create your own server template for your specific need rather than extending them using CompositeTemplates.

---

If you do not want to Create a new server template, you can use the [updateEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) API to update the recipient type.

Here are the steps

1. Create the envelope as a **Draft** (Status = 'Created')
2. Use the [updateEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) API to **update** the recipient type to CertifiedDelivery. Any tabs that are associated with the recipient will be removed.
3. **Send** the Envelope using the [updateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) Api.

---

Another Hack that seems to work. ( I do not recommend this)

You can change the **routingOrder** of the recipient. The recipient will then be considered as the certified Delivery Recipient as it will no longer match the recipient in the server template.

From [Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#composite-templates) (Expand the compositeTemplates section)

> **Recipient matching** is based on Recipient Role and Routing Order. If there are matches, the recipient information is merged together. A final pass is done on all Composite Templates, after all template overlays have been applied, to collapse recipients with the same email, username and routing order. This prevents having the same recipients at the same routing order.

Comment: So in this case, where there is only one recipient involved, what would you set the routing Order to in order to get around this?

Comment: Changing a RecipientType on a Server Template just does not feel like a good use of Server Templates. It means you have not defined your server template correctly.  You should create another ServerTemplate with the appropriate recipient types and use that instead.

Comment: With our application, we hope to only have a few templates with maybe 8 or 10 template roles. We're trying to keep housekeeping on the templates to a minimum, not a one to one for each document. Anyway, what I need to know is for those times where they want recipient x to just view the docs and be a certified delivery person and I need to make sure that they don't get any signing tabs. There will be instances of that.

Comment: Updated my answer to use the **updateEnvelopeRecipients** api.  This is cleaner than using the compositeTemplates to change the recipient type.

Comment: I think my best option to this is to have a Certified Delivery recipient on all the templates, even if it is not used a whole lot. Since I don't need to have all my recipients filled in all the time, I can use this particular template role for those times when documents get sent out and only need to be looked at.